# Redefine 'widget' function in Wordpress CMS

Tags: php, wordpress

Now I create new simple wordpress theme.

Tell me please, how can I redefine **widget** public function defined in the file?: **wordpress-dir/wp-includes/widgets/class-wp-widget-tag-cloud.php**.

So I need to remove `<div class="tagcloud">` html tag without editing core **WP** file.

What did I try: in theme's **functions.php** I defined new function named as new_widget (with arguments: `$args, $instance`), inserted code below to function and called `add_filter('widget', 'new_widget');`:

```
$current_taxonomy = $this->_get_current_taxonomy( $instance );

if ( ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ) {
  $title = $instance['title'];
} else {
  if ( 'post_tag' === $current_taxonomy ) {
    $title = __( 'Tags' );
  } else {
    $tax = get_taxonomy( $current_taxonomy );
    $title = $tax->labels->name;
  }
}

$show_count = ! empty( $instance['count'] );

/**
* Filters the taxonomy used in the Tag Cloud widget.
*
* @since 2.8.0
* @since 3.0.0 Added taxonomy drop-down.
* @since 4.9.0 Added the `$instance` parameter.
*
* @see wp_tag_cloud()
*
* @param array $args     Args used for the tag cloud widget.
* @param array $instance Array of settings for the current widget.
*/
$tag_cloud = wp_tag_cloud( apply_filters( 'widget_tag_cloud_args', array(
  'taxonomy'   => $current_taxonomy,
  'echo'       => false,
  'show_count' => $show_count,
), $instance ) );

if ( empty( $tag_cloud ) ) {
  return;
}

/** This filter is documented in wp-includes/widgets/class-wp-widget-pages.php */
$title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $title, $instance, $this->id_base );

echo $args['before_widget'];
if ( $title ) {
  echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];
}

echo $tag_cloud;

echo $args['after_widget'];
function glurion_widget( $args, $instance ) {
  $current_taxonomy = $this->_get_current_taxonomy( $instance );

if ( ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ) {
  $title = $instance['title'];
} else {
  if ( 'post_tag' === $current_taxonomy ) {
   $title = __( 'Tags' );
  } else {
    $tax = get_taxonomy( $current_taxonomy );
    $title = $tax->labels->name;
  }
}

$show_count = ! empty( $instance['count'] );

/**
* Filters the taxonomy used in the Tag Cloud widget.
*
* @since 2.8.0
* @since 3.0.0 Added taxonomy drop-down.
* @since 4.9.0 Added the `$instance` parameter.
*
* @see wp_tag_cloud()
*
* @param array $args     Args used for the tag cloud widget.
* @param array $instance Array of settings for the current widget.
*/
$tag_cloud = wp_tag_cloud( apply_filters( 'widget_tag_cloud_args', array(
  'taxonomy'   => $current_taxonomy,
  'echo'       => false,
  'show_count' => $show_count,
 ), $instance ) );

if ( empty( $tag_cloud ) ) {
  return;
}

/** This filter is documented in wp-includes/widgets/class-wp-widget-pages.php */
$title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $title, $instance, $this->id_base );

echo $args['before_widget'];
if ( $title ) {
  echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];
}

/** Commented: echo '<div class="tagcloud">'; */

echo $tag_cloud;

/** Commented: echo "</div>\n"; */
echo $args['after_widget'];
```

So... in my tag cloud in wordpress page I saw the removed html tags.

Comment: What you want to do? you want to create your own custom widget or want to extend the core widget?

Comment: I want to edit custom core widget, not extend.

Comment: you can't directly edit or extend any widget in wordpress. you need to define your own custom widget file in `wp-admin/plugins/custom_foldername\filename.php`. In this file you can extend the widget. For help follow this link: (https://www.cssigniter.com/extending-wordpress-core-3rd-party-widgets/).